# Binding form controls based on table fields in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I started new project in window application, My requirement for the project is : 
1) create dynamic forms.
2) previously i added some the setting in the table tbl_settings.newly added dynamic forms should contains controls which are selected in the setting form(saved in tbl_setting table).
 for example setting form contains 
i)name of the form ii) current date check box iii) address check box iv) name check box v)gender  
 while adding dynamic form customer i'll check i,ii,iii,iv,v but while creating company form i'll select only i,ii,iii,iv not v that time by seeing dynamic forms company i'll get to enter only **name of the form in the form header,current date text box,address text box,name text box should be available in the form** & something in the customer except to gender drop down list etc in that form. 

 `Is it possible to create dynamic forms & fields in window forms?` 

 Why i'm asking like this means in visual foxpro this option provided using control source property.
 thanks in advance & replies are appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to generate dynamic forms but you need to take care of size and point/location of the object within form. Have you look into the file xyzClass.designer.cs which automatically generated/modified when you drag n drop controls onto the forms ?, this is how you have to do that and assign dynamic values from Database while creating the object.

for e.g adding a label to win form programmatically.

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Label lblDynamic;
lblDynamic = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();

lblDynamic.AutoSize = true;
lblDynamic.Enabled = false;
lblDynamic.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(291, 68);
lblDynamic.Name = "lblDynamic";
lblDynamic.Text = "My dynamic label";
lblDynamic.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 13);
lblDynamic.TabIndex = 1;
lblDynamic.Visible = false;
Form1.Controls.Add(this.lblDynamic);
Form1.Show();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you please elaborate bit more.